# Bootstrap Modal Hiding when form submitted using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap 3 (not Angular-UI Bootstrap). Whenever I submit a form in a modal using `ng-submit`, the modal closes automatically and leaves a `div.modal-backdrop` on the body.

This is only happening when I'm doing `$http.put` from Angular. If I remove the AJAX code, the modal stays open.

So how do I make the modal stay open when Angular is making the request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom-defined ng-submit function instead of the form's submit method. I have something similar here: https://github.com/librecms/librecms/blob/master/src/angular/app/views/widgets/auth.html#L2.

Comment: I'm using `ng-submit` already. The modal only closes when I make the HTTP Request... I edited the question too.